# Home tab setting in salesforce for a profile

Tags: lightning-experience, administration, sales-cloud

How to enable home tab setting to default on for a particular profile? I am not able to edit from object setting in profile.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Home tab settings are 'Default On' (read-only) under 'Tab Settings' on profile.
Follow the below steps to restore the Home tab to your profile

In Lightning Experience UI:

1. Click on Setup | Users | User Management Settings |

   a) Disable Enhanced Profile User Interface.
   b) Click on Save.

In Classic UI:

1. Click on Setup | Manage Users | User Management Settings |

   a) Disable Enhanced Profile User Interface.
   b) Click on Save.
2. Enable Overwrite users personal tab customization

   a) Go to Setup | Manage Users | Profiles
   b) Click on Edit on affected Profile
   c) Go to Tab Settings
   d) Check the box for Overwrite Users Personal tab Customization
   c) Click on Save.

Check more details [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000318544&type=1&mode=1)

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Vinay! after this disabling this setting still the Home tab is not available for the profile. Though its showing default on in the tab setting. Do you know why like that?

Comment: Strange, Can you try enabling 'Overwrite users' personal tab customizations' and check App settings and set 'Default Landing Tab' to Home tab.